# Группировка строк в массиве по определенным элементам

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день.
Я вытягиваю через PHPExcel данные. В итоге получаю вот такой массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => (888301004)
            [2] => Школьная
            [3] => 1/2
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 7/13/1970
            [6] => Иванов
            [7] => 01.07.2015-01.02.2016 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 1/31/2017
            [10] => 26,947.13
            [11] => 7,386.54
            [12] => 615.00
            [13] => 2-548-2/2017 от 03.02.2017
            [14] => 4/10/2017
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => (888301004)
            [2] => Школьная
            [3] => 1/2
            [4] => 4
            [5] => 9/7/1997
            [6] => Петров
            [7] => 01.07.2015-01.02.2016 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 1/31/2017
            [10] => 26,947.13
            [11] => 7,386.54
            [12] => 615.00
            [13] => 2-548-2/2017 от 03.02.2017
            [14] => 4/10/2017
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => (8881324809)
            [2] => СУ-80
            [3] => 7Р
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 3/10/1959
            [6] => Сидоров
            [7] => 01.05.2015-01.01.2016 
            [8] => (на 01.12.2016г.)
            [9] => 1/31/2017
            [10] => 15,989.91
            [11] => 5,080.56
            [12] => 416.06
            [13] => 2-608-3
            [14] => 4/10/2017
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => (8881324809)
            [2] => СУ-80
            [3] => 7Р
            [4] => 6
            [5] => 3/10/1959
            [6] => Васильев
            [7] => 01.05.2015-01.01.2016 
            [8] => (на 01.12.2016г.)
            [9] => 1/31/2017
            [10] => 15,989.91
            [11] => 5,080.56
            [12] => 416.06
            [13] => 2-608-3
            [14] => 4/10/2017
        )
```

Как можно сгруппировать эти данные при совпадении элементов 0 и 1 и 7 и 10 и 11 и 12, чтобы в итоге получить такой массив:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => (888301004)
            [2] => 01.07.2015-01.02.2016 
            [3] => 26,947.13
            [4] => 7,386.54
            [5] => 615.00
            [6] => 2-548-2/2017 от 03.02.2017
            [7] => 4/10/2017
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19
            [1] => (8881324809)
            [2] => 01.05.2015-01.01.2016 
            [3] => 15,989.91
            [4] => 5,080.56
            [5] => 416.06
            [6] => 2-608-3/2017 от 10.02.2017
            [7] => 4/10/2017
        )
```

То есть в результате хотелось бы получить некий массив с уникальными строками.

Comment: вы забыли про `14` или на каком основании определяется 7-е значение резульирующего массива?

Comment: что то не понятен вопрос немного

Comment: 13, 14 и все конечные элементы - они всегда на 100% совпадают, если совпадают первые перечисленные. Их просто добавляем к результирующему массиву.

Comment: алгоритм то вроде не сложный, вы пробовали вообще решить сию задачу? сначала выкиньте из массива не нужные элементы. потом проходитесь по нему, для каждого элемента составлете некий "ключ", банально конкатенацией значений, складываете их в новый массив. Далее array_unique оставит вам уникальные ключи (первые) с сохранением индексов. Затем заберете данные по этим индексам.

Comment: [Это](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge.php) подойдет?

Comment: @DNS а как это может подойти?

Comment: @teran, чат в ответах, вроде, не приветствуется. Я вообще-то у ТС спросил... Не подходит - значит нет. Есть и другие джоины.

Comment: Мне вообще кажется, что эти данные вы где-нибудь из БД берете. И что-то мне подсказывает, что можно сделать просто правильный запрос. А так кажется вы хотите что-то противозаконное сделать

Answer (score 1):

Предложу следующий вариант решения задачи.

Исходные данные:

```
$data = [ 
    [ 19, "(888301004)", "Школьная", "1/2", 4, "7/13/1970", "Иванов", "01.07.2015-01.02.2016 ", "", "1/31/2017", "26,947.13", "7,386.54", "615.00", "2-548-2/2017 от 03.02.2017", "4/10/2017" ],
    [ 19, "(888301004)", "Школьная", "1/2", 4, "9/7/1997", "Петров", "01.07.2015-01.02.2016 ", "", "1/31/2017", "26,947.13", "7,386.54", "615.00", "2-548-2/2017 от 03.02.2017", "4/10/2017", ],
    [ 19, "(8881324809)", "СУ-80", "7Р", 6, "3/10/1959", "Сидоров", "01.05.2015-01.01.2016 ", "(на 01.12.2016г.)", "1/31/2017", "15,989.91", "5,080.56", "416.06", "2-608-3", "4/10/2017", ],
    [ 19, "(8881324809)", "СУ-80", "7Р", 6, "3/10/1959", "Васильев", "01.05.2015-01.01.2016 ", "(на 01.12.2016г.)", "1/31/2017", "15,989.91", "5,080.56", "416.06", "2-608-3", "4/10/2017", ]
];
```

Определим ключи (индексы), которые нам необходимо оставить в результирующем наборе:

```
$pkeys = [0,1,7,10,11,12,13,14];
$keys = array_flip($pkeys);
```

Определим массив для хранения уникальных "хэшей" элементов.

```
$uniq = [];
```

Пройдемся по массиву, сначала оставив только нужные данные с помощью [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-intersect-key.php), заодно получим хэш элемента, просто склеив все в строку с помощью [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

```
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    $data[$k] = array_intersect_key($v, $keys);
    $uniq[] = implode("|", $data[$k]);
}
```

оставим только уникальные "хэши" с помощью [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-unique.php) при этом сохраняются индексы.

```
 $uniq = array_unique($uniq);
```

вернемся к массиву `$data` и оставим из него только полученные уникальные инексы, опять с помощью `array_intersect_key()`:

```
$data = array_intersect_key($data, $uniq);
```

---

Полностью код (если убрать промежуточные строки) такой:

```
$keys = array_flip([0,1,7,10,11,12,13,14]);
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    $data[$k] = array_intersect_key($v, $keys);
    $uniq[$k] = implode("|", $data[$k]);
}
$data = array_intersect_key($data, array_unique($uniq));
```

---

Если необходимо сбросить нумерацию элементов, то в цикле

```
$data[$k] = array_values(....);
```